# show and hide divs jfiddle issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my problem is, i'm trying to create 3 or 4 levels of select options, and the next option is determined by the previous option, and the select functions get generated from a mysql call which isnt important. As you can see A1>B1>C1 works, But A2>B2>? Does nothing

```
 $("#category").change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "A1") { $("#A1").show(); }
     else { $("#A1").hide(); } 

    if ($(this).val() == "A2") { $("#A2").show(); }
     else { $("#A2").hide(); } 
 });

 $("#subcategory").change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "B1") { $("#B1").show(); }
     else { $("#B1").hide(); } 

    if ($(this).val() == "B2") {  $("#B2").show(); }
     else {  $("#B2").hide(); } 
 });

 $("#nextcategory").change(function() {

    if ($(this).val() == "C1") { $("#C1").show(); }
     else { $("#C1").hide(); } 

    if ($(this).val() == "C2") {  $("#C2").show(); }
     else {  $("#C2").hide(); } 
 });
```

Comment: You didn't include jquery.

Comment: **Working here ==>** `:)` http://jsfiddle.net/Tdhd7/

Comment: it is working fine you have not include jquery library in the fiddle

Comment: thanks, give me a second to update my question, because this wasnt the original issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used same `id`s multiple times.

`ID`s must be unique.

Change

```
$("#subcategory").change(function() {
$("#nextcategory").change(function() {
```

to

```
$("select[name='subcategory']").change(function() {...
$("select[name='nextcategory']").change(function() {...
```

Write:

```
$("#category").change(function () {
     $("#A1,#A2").hide();
     if ($(this).val() == "A1") {
         $("#A1").show();
     } else if ($(this).val() == "A2") {
         $("#A2").show();
     }
 });

 $("select[name='subcategory']").change(function () {
     $("#B1,#B2").hide();
     if ($(this).val() == "B1") {
         $("#B1").show();
     } else if ($(this).val() == "B2") {
         $("#B2").show();
     }
 });
 $("select[name='nextcategory']").change(function () {
     $("#C1,#C2").hide();
     if ($(this).val() == "C1") {
         $("#C1").show();
     } else if ($(this).val() == "C2") {
         $("#C2").show();
     }
 });
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tdhd7/12/)

Answer (score 0):

missing this in header it seems, i added its working pretty!!!!

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```